# SQL Server WITH not working, invalid syntax?

Tags: sql-server, syntax, sql-server-2000, with-statement

Using the following query,

```
WITH 
    cteTest (Employee_ID)
    AS
    (
        SELECT employee_ID FROM pep.dbo.labor_ticket
    )
SELECT Employee_ID FROM cteTest;
```

I get the following return:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
```

Looks right to me.  I asked a similar question about a subquery but the same logic does not apply here as I have aliased the table with the name cteTest.  What's missing?

Comment: This works for me, so you probably have a problem with code surrounding it.

Comment: Nothing surrounding it whatsoever.  I even highlight and execute, same deal... no CTE's will evaluate for me.  Exit/Re-Open MGMT studio, same thing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this particular database is on SQL Server 8.0 which does not support CTE.  Looks like I'll have to settle with subqueries.

Figures, working for a company with 3 different versions of SQL Server that I would have overlooked this.  The other servers are 9.0 and support this functionality just fine and I've never had to write something with a CTE against this particular DB, learn something new every day :)

Comment: Yes, CTE means SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a semicolon in front of the "WITH".

```
;WITH 
    cteTest (Employee_ID)
    AS
    (
        SELECT employee_ID FROM pep.dbo.labor_ticket
    )
SELECT Employee_ID FROM cteTest;
```

Comment: Its not about starting the query with a semi-colon; its about ending the previous query with a semi-colon.